# A variable and its pointer, have different values

Tags: c++

Look at this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 const int x = 0;
 int *p;

 p=(int*)&x;
 (*p)++;

 cout<<x<<endl;
 cout<<*p;
}
```

As you see above, I declared `x` as a `const int`, and using casting, a non const pointer named `p` is points to it. In the middle of the body of my program, I increased the value of `x` by one  using `(*p)++` (How is it possible, while `x` is defined as const?)

Now,when I print `*p` and `x`, they returns different values, while `*p` is supposed to point to address of `x` :

```
ap1019@sharifvm:~$ ./a.out
0
1
```

Why?

Comment: removing const is `undefined behaviour.` Now you can see why.

Comment: Are your legs still with you?

Comment: @user3528438 What does that mean?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92126/what-did-bjarne-stroustrup-mean-by-his-characterization-of-c-and-c

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clear why you get the behaviour you get, and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change of variable after constant removal causes the **undefined behaviour**, in some cases it will just work as if it wouldn't be const, in some it will cause the memory violation error, in some, it will turn your computer into the rabbit which will try to kill you...

A bit of background on the behaviour. Imagine you are a compiler. You encounter the variable:

```
const int blah = 3;
```

And then you encounter the following operation:

```
int foo = 4 + blah;
```

As you are smart compiler and you know that blah is constant - therefore it will not change, instead of reading the value from the blah, you can exchange the value from get the blah storage place in memory read it to simply add the 3 to 4 and assign it to foo.

Infant you will probably assign 7 straight away because doing the addition is pointless each time you run the program.

Lets now get into the casting away the const part.

Some really sneaky programmer is doing the following:

```
int * blah_pointer = (int *) & blah;
```

Then he is increasing the blah value by doing this operation:

```
(*blah_pointer)++;
```

What will happen - if the variable is not in the protected memory (not read only) the program will just increase the value of variable stored in memory.

Now when you will read the value which is stored in the pointer you will get the increased value!

Ok but why is there an old, unchanged value if you are reading just the blah I hear you ask:

```
std::cout << blah;
```

It is there, because the compiler try to be smart and instead of actually reading the value from blah it will just exchange it to a constant value to blah, so instead of reading it it will actually exchange it to std::cout << 3.

The undefined part is changing the constant value - you can't ever know whether the value will be stored in protected or unprotected region therefore you can't tell what will happen.

If you want the compiler to actually check the value each time it encounters it just change the definition from:

```
const int blah = 3;
```

to

```
const volatile int blah = 3;
```

It will tell the compiler the following, even though the program I am writing is not allowed to change the blah value, it may be changed during the execution of the program, therefore do not try to optimise the access to the memory and read it every time the value is used.

I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: It's not the removal that will kill you, it's the assignment.

Comment: It is said that it has undefined behaviour, but most compilers have a specific way of doing it, no ?

Comment: @milleniumbug yes sorry I wasn't precise enough.

Comment: @Othman no, it is not only compiler specific behaviour, it is also dependant where in memory it will happen, on which platform you use, on which os and many more things. Those bugs can be also quite tricky to debug because when you are using the debugger the memory protection may be different which will cause the bug to be not reproducible under debugger so you shouldn't really do it unless you are sure that it is the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think, in compilation step, your compiler will replace all your constant variables with its values (it's like `#define`), it's the way GNU GCC compiler optimize the code.
I'm not 100% sure about it, but i've got the same issue while learning C/C++ syntax, and it's the conclusion that i've made after disassebling (converting the binary executable to assembler code) my program.
Anyways, just try to disassemble your output and see what is really happening.

Comment: Do you have any references ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but i got the same question while learning C, using GNU GCC compiler. And my conclusion above is what i got after disassembling the output program.